Text-to-image generation using randomseed API
I'm trying to use random-seed API to generate text-to-image
Post request is fine, and it's giving a unique ID in response to fetch the result
But when it's throwing an error like the below when fetching results using this API https://randomseed.lol/v1/status/${REQUEST_ID}", I also added webhook; it's not even being called
Request:
curl --location "https://randomseed.lol/v1/txt2img" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $RANDOMSEED_API_KEY" \
  --data '{
      "txt2img": {
          "prompt": "Cute cat",
          "negative_prompt": "ugly, out of frame",
          "width": "512",
          "height": "512",
          "number_of_images": "1",
          "steps": "20",
          "cfg_scale": 7,
          "sampler_name": "Euler a",
          "model_name": "realistic_vision_v4",
        "webhook":${HOST_NAME}/app/webhook/${appId}/result/${trackId},
          "track_id": 1,
          "seed": "-1",
      }
  }'

response
{
    "delayTime": 152,
    "error": "AUTOMATIC_ERROR: {\"error\":\"HTTPException\",\"detail\":\"Script 'ADetailer' not found\",\"body\":\"\",\"errors\":\"\"}",
    "executionTime": 17270,
    "id": "6dc2da82-afd9-4030-9cda-ce03816479c2-u1",
    "output": {
        "body": "{\"error\":\"HTTPException\",\"detail\":\"Script 'ADetailer' not found\",\"body\":\"\",\"errors\":\"\"}",
        "generation_time": 0.002918720245361328,
        "statusCode": 422
    },
    "status": "FAILED"
}

I used the payload, which is in a random seed document

Please add enough (relevant) code to create a [mre]
